# -bash: gt: command not found

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal

I downloaded some GitHub file a long time ago that I honestly don't even need anymore. Anyways, now whenever I open/start or even do anything, it gives me this error that says

```
-bash: gt: command not found
-bash: /dev/null: Permission denied
fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'.
```

Also, instead of saying

```
user@ubuntu; ~ $
```

It says

```
-&gt;&gt; ~ $
```

I'm also on Mac running a Terminal clone

Comment: Can you post your `.bashrc`? (minus any secret stuff, of course)

Comment: "The file /Users/gizmopena/.bashrc does not exist". Also sry im a noob

Comment: Hm, interesting. So, when you say "I downloaded some GitHub file a long time ago", presumably you mean you added something from GitHub to your startup. Is this correct? Could you run this command for me: `echo $SHELL`

Comment: In github you need to click the "Raw" button before downloading a file. Otherwise, you're probably downloading the HTML rendering of the file. If you open/edit the file you downloaded, it should be evident. Does `/Users` exist? That doesn't sound like a normal Ubuntu home folder for user accounts. Usually it's `/home/...`. If you login, what do you get when you enter `pwd`?

Comment: Do any of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, or `~/.profile` exist? If so, what do they contain?

Comment: @jwir3 im pretty sure that's exactly what I did

Comment: @lurker when I run `pwd` I get `/Users/gizmopena`

Comment: I am on Mac running an ubuntu terminal clone. when I run `open ~/.bash_profile` I get this: `export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxBexport CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxBxCxDxexegedabagaced
 
parse_git_branch() {
   git branch 2&gt; /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
 
export PS1="\e[0;35m-&gt;&gt; \e[1;34m\W\e[0;32m\$(parse_git_branch)\e[0;37m $ "
`

Comment: @Gizmo: Remove the function (everything from `parse_git_branch()` until `$ "`). That should fix the issue.

Comment: @Gizmo thanks, I don't realize you were on a Mac. You need to edit your question and our the shell script there, not in a comment where it's hard to read and hard to find for new readers.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that your shell prompt (stuff that your shell shows when waiting for you to enter some command) contains wrong characters. Looking at `.bash_profile` you've provided in the comments, it appears that PS1 variable definition contains weird characters, plus it calls `parse_git_branch` function that itself has a number of issues (most likely the result of HTML copy/paste).

You have 2 options:

1. Remove the function and redefine PS1 to something more useful. Your `.bash_profile` would look something like this:

```sh
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxBxCxDxexegedabagaced

export PS1="[\u@\h \W] \$ "
```

2. Just fix copy/paste issues to bring your prompt to its intended form, which is "show me the current working directory and, when available, current git branch":

```sh
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxBxCxDxexegedabagaced
parse_git_branch() { 
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/' 
} 

export PS1="\[\e[0;35m\]->> \[\e[1;34m\]\W\[\e[0;32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[0;37m\] $ "
```

Comment: There is an online guide that contains some typos on `.bash_profile`: http://voidcanvas.com/ubuntu-like-mac-terminal/ solution provided here by @KMZ works fine.